# Get InnerHTML of element that isnt inside another tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

So if I had

```
<div id="outside">
   Hello
   <div id="inside">
       Qwertyuiop
   </div>
</div>
```

How would I get the InnerHTML of the outside without including anything from the inside or any other HTML tags? (bascially how to get "Hello")

Answer (score 4):

### 1 An interesting option:

This is not a serious answer, and is based on `Darin Morris'` highly destructive answer but is slightly less destructive:

```
// Clone the element
var $clone = $("#outside").clone();

// Remove all the children (leaves text nodes)
$clone.children().remove();

alert($clone.text());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ez4v83v5/4/

Again I would not recommend this as an alternative to say

### 2 My serious answer:

```
$('#outside')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
```

*but who knows... This technique may come in handy for someone at some point* :)

Comment: P.S. Downvoters on this answer have a) no sense of humour and b) no sense of the ridiculous :)

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
$(function(){
   var theHtml = $("#outside");
   var texto = theHtml[0].childNodes[0].data;
   alert((texto));
});
```

Fiddle:

```js
$(function() {
  var theHtml = $("#outside");
  var texto = theHtml[0].childNodes[0].data;
  alert((texto));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outside">
  Hello
  <div id="inside">
    Qwertyuiop
  </div>
</div>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: `theHtml[0].firstChild.nodeValue` is shorter/faster.

Comment: I would guess the difference is a very trivial speed increase (as it avoids one array indexing operation), but I would err on the side of *shorter* anyway.

Comment: Yep...it is shorter...but no faster...there is a difference between 1 or 2 miliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `.contents()` at this context

```js
alert($("#outside").contents().first()[0].nodeValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outside">
   Hello
   <div id="inside">
       Qwertyuiop
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: `first()[0]` is redundant. `$("#outside").contents()[0].nodeValue` does the same thing :)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get the value of the first child so

```js
alert($('#outside').prop('firstChild').nodeValue)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outside">
   Hello
   <div id="inside">
       Qwertyuiop
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it better to use `prop` for HTML element properties (rather than just `$('#outside')[0].firstChild.nodeValue)`?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I really don't see much difference.. except that using `.prop()` will need to run some jQuery code again

Comment: Okay. If you have no preference, maybe just avoid the overhead of `prop` then? (either will break if there is no child, so jQuery `prop` is not really adding any value). +1 anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.prototype.filter.call(document.querySelector('#outside').childNodes, function (node) {
    return node.nodeValue;
});
```

You can also try this in Vanilla, it would also handle a case if you had other strings after the div.

Answer (score 0):

There probably is a better way to do this, but this should work for you:

```
var kids = $("#outside").children();

for(var i = 0; i < kids.length; i++)
{
    if(kids[i].nodeType != 3)
    {
        $(kids[i]).remove();
    }
}

alert($("#outside").text());
```

See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ez4v83v5/1

Comment: No, actually it wasn't good enough. 

The question did not specifically state whether or not only the first text node was specifically required or if the first text node would be the first child node of the parent.

My solution solves that problem and gets all text contents regardless of the placement of the text within the parent element's contents.

For what its worth, $("#outside").children().remove(); should work but it don't work in JSFiddle and so I didn't recommend it. It's possible its a bug with JSFiddle...

Comment: -1: All joking aside, the above code destroys the DOM elements in the process of extracting the text node value. It also uses a completely redundant `for` loop and `if` check as `children` does not return elements of `nodeType` 3. You get the same effect with `$("#outside").children().remove();` http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ez4v83v5/5/ Basically it is not only DOM-destructive, but also inefficient too.

Comment: Ok, well thats fine. There is a reason I made a point of saying 'it could probably be done better'... ("#outside").children().remove(); seems to work in your JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

try the jquery api **children**, try the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d88unueh/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($('#outside').clone()    //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove()   //remove all the children
    .end()  //again go back to selected element
    .text());

});
```

hope it helps...

Comment: The aim was to get `Hello` (which is a text node, invisible to `children()`), not `Qwertyuiop`. Sorry.